# Convert SqlCommand to T-SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have an `SqlCommand` with parameters. Due to some external requirement (see PS), I need *one T-SQL string* instead, i.e., I need `... @parameter ...`  replaced by `... the-value-of-@parameter-encoded-correctly ...` (e.g. `O'Brien` --> `'O''Brien'`, `02 Mar 2010` --> `'20100302'`, `3.5` --> `3.5`).

I know that I could home-brew such a solution quite easily, but correct escaping is tricky (make sure you get the right date and number formats, watch for quote signs in strings, etc.), and I guess that I'm not the only one needing this, so my question is:

**Is there an existing solution for converting an SqlCommand with parameters into a single T-SQL statements with the parameters embedded and correctly escaped?**

PS: We need to do that because we need to use the `SqlCommand` as a data source for an MS Access report... and "pass-though querydefs" in Access don't support parameterized SQLs.

PPS: I know that there are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964459/sqlcommand-to-t-sql) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926142/how-does-sqlcommand-net-sanitize-parameters), but they all assume that SQL Server somehow does this conversion (`@parameter` --> some escaped string representing the value), so the answers ("SQL Server doesn't do that") do not apply here. I understand that there is no such conversion happening in SQL Server.

Comment: I don't want to be negative, but as other questions have clarified - and as you mentioned yourself - the TSQL string you're looking for is never generated anyway. So I'm not sure exactly what answer you expect to get, other than to roll your own or modify your application somehow?

Comment: @Pondlife: I hope for an answer of this kind: "Yes, I've had this problem before and I've written and published a routine in C#/VB {link to source} which escapes all kinds of values properly according to the SQL Server escaping spec found at {link to MSDN}."

Answer (score 5):

I think it is far clearer to write out the SQL query with the parameters and have a few `DECLARE @p1 type;` and `SET @p1 = 'value';` lines before your primary SELECT query and leave the original query text in the `SqlCommand` instance unchanged. I have some example code which does this if you'd like to see that.

If you're really adamant about simply doing parameter value substitution within the query text, then find yourself a T-SQL grammar specific to the server you're talking to, parse the query until you find a parameter reference, and replace it with text according to the T-SQL grammar's escaping rules for strings.

**EDIT**:

Since I'm such a fantastic guy, I'll get you started on your way to formatting SQL parameters for output with proper escaping. This is woefully incomplete since it does not handle every single database type known to man and SQL Server, but it gets the job done for me in that it handles my most commonly-used types. As I said in my comment, simply escaping the single-quote character as two single-quote characters in succession seems to suffice for proper string-value escaping. You'll have to double and triple check the T-SQL grammars used by the various SQL Server versions to make sure this is good enough.

```
private static string FormatSqlValue(System.Data.Common.DbParameter prm)
{
    if (prm.Value == DBNull.Value) return "NULL";
    switch (prm.DbType)
    {
        case System.Data.DbType.Int32: return (prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.String: return String.Format("'{0}'", ScrubSqlString((string)prm.Value));
        case System.Data.DbType.AnsiString: return String.Format("'{0}'", ScrubSqlString((string)prm.Value));
        case System.Data.DbType.Boolean: return ((bool)prm.Value ? "1" : "0");
        case System.Data.DbType.DateTime: return String.Format("'{0}'", prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.DateTime2: return String.Format("'{0}'", prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.Decimal: return (prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.Guid: return String.Format("'{0}'", prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.Double: return (prm.Value.ToString());
        case System.Data.DbType.Byte: return (prm.Value.ToString());
        // TODO: more conversions.
        default: return (prm.DbType.ToString());
    }
}

private static string FormatSqlValue(Type type, object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return "NULL";
    // Handle Nullable<T> types:
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        // If the Nullabe<T> value has been found to have !HasValue, return "NULL":
        if (!(bool)type.GetProperty("HasValue").GetValue(value, null))
            return "NULL";
        // Try our best to format the underlying non-nullable value now:
        return FormatSqlValue(type.GetGenericArguments()[0], type.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(value, null));
    }
    if (type == typeof(Int32)) return value.ToString();
    if (type == typeof(String)) return String.Format("'{0}'", ScrubSqlString((string)value));
    if (type == typeof(Boolean)) return ((bool)value ? "1" : "0");
    if (type == typeof(DateTime)) return String.Format("'{0}'", value.ToString());
    if (type == typeof(Decimal)) return (value.ToString());
    if (type == typeof(Guid)) return String.Format("'{0}'", value.ToString());
    if (type == typeof(Double)) return (value.ToString());
    if (type == typeof(Byte)) return (value.ToString());
    // TODO: complete the mapping...
    return value.ToString();
}

private static string ScrubSqlString(string value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < value.Length)
    {
        if (value[i] == '\'')
        {
            sb.Append("\'\'");
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(value[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static string FormatSqlParameter(System.Data.Common.DbParameter prm)
{
    StringBuilder sbDecl = new StringBuilder();
    sbDecl.Append(prm.ParameterName);
    sbDecl.Append(' ');
    switch (prm.DbType)
    {
        case System.Data.DbType.Int32: sbDecl.Append("int"); break;
        // SQL does not like defining nvarchar(0).
        case System.Data.DbType.String: sbDecl.AppendFormat("nvarchar({0})", prm.Size == -1 ? "max" : prm.Size == 0 ? "1" : prm.Size.ToString()); break;
        // SQL does not like defining varchar(0).
        case System.Data.DbType.AnsiString: sbDecl.AppendFormat("varchar({0})", prm.Size == -1 ? "max" : prm.Size == 0 ? "1" : prm.Size.ToString()); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.Boolean: sbDecl.Append("bit"); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.DateTime: sbDecl.Append("datetime"); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.DateTime2: sbDecl.Append("datetime2"); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.Decimal: sbDecl.Append("decimal"); break;  // FIXME: no precision info in DbParameter!
        case System.Data.DbType.Guid: sbDecl.Append("uniqueidentifier"); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.Double: sbDecl.Append("double"); break;
        case System.Data.DbType.Byte: sbDecl.Append("tinyint"); break;
        // TODO: more conversions.
        default: sbDecl.Append(prm.DbType.ToString()); break;
    }
    return sbDecl.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks, that's a nice approach. However, the original problem still remains, because `SET @p1 = 'value'` requires the same kind of escaping as `WHERE myfield = 'value'`. So "escaping according to the grammar rules" is required in *both* cases. Do you have a link to the "escaping rules" for SQL Server? (Questions for such "escape rules" on SO are immediately answered with "just use parameterized queries", which is not extremely helpful in this case...)

Comment: I realized that after I posted :) Sorry about that one. I only did basic string-escaping rules that worked "well enough" for my display purposes. If you just cover escaping the quote characters, I *think* you're all set.

Comment: @Heinzi: I updated the answer with code I've developed for my SQL auditing tool which displays SQL code to a human user, not intended for parsing by a T-SQL engine. You'll find TODOs and FIXMEs noted as to where things can be improved, if possible. Hope that helps!

Comment: @James: Thanks, that's definitely a nice starting point! One of the things that will obviously break is the use of `ToString` without a culture specifier: On my German system, this would return `3,5` for a double and `'31.12.2010'` for a datetime, both of which will cause SQL Server to choke (btw, the correct input, which SQL Server will always accept independent of any localization settings, is `'20101231'`, if I remember correctly). ...

Comment: @James: ...That, actually, was the main reason for my question: Since there are so many "small issues" to be thought of, I was wondering if someone already wrote "production quality" library code for this common problem. (But don't get me wrong: I still appreciate your help!)

Comment: @Heinzi: Good points! Would updating the `ToString` calls with the invariant culture formatter suffice?

Comment: @James: I guess so; a cast would be required in this case, since Object.ToString does not support parameters. Just out of curiosity: Couldn't you reduce `ScrubSqlString` to the one-liner `return value.Replace("'", "''");`?

Comment: @Heinzi: Prrrrrobably :-D. I thought it was going to be more complicated than that when I wrote it, and it obviously ended up not being so.